# Bios stopped boot from usb

Tags: boot, usb, bios, grub

my pc is an ASUS RoG g750jx with dual boot : Debian Jessie and windows 8.1 ,  until yesterday everything was fine. Yesterday booting my pc it didn't display GRUB and directly booted to Windows,i thought : "not bad i just have to reinstall GRUB". I wanted to boot from usb (it works on others computers) using a Debian-live ,as soon as pc boot i press ESC key to get the boot override menu' , from the list i select the usb device after few istants it send me to BIOS. it happens with every usb i tried (i tried all the ports). Until yesterday i was able to boot from usb without problems ,since my GRUB is magically disappeared i can't boot no more . Seems like some sort of error during usb boot that sends me to BIOS.

Bios settings :

secure boot : disabled
Legacy      : disabled 
Usb support : enabled

I didn't change any settings and before yester with the same configuration i was able to boot from USB device!

Answer (score 1):

In BIOS-> security, your USB interface could be set to "lock".

Comment: BIOS -> security USB is set on "Unlock"

Comment: Can you update the BIOS from the BIOS using USB?  Does USB work in windows?

Comment: yes and i've alredy update the BIOS . Yes USB works in Windows . Can be an UEFI problem?

Comment: Is CSM enabled? Secure boot disabled and enable CSM (sometimes Launch CSM)

Comment: CSM is disabled cause i was able to boot without any problem since 2 days ago :( . Yes , secure boot is disabled. Now i remeber that Windows 8 did an update could be that ruined uefi ?